# When first time loading Ads, app closing automatically

Tags: java, android, admob, google-play-services, ads

When my app loading for first time, it doesn't loading ads and closing. If I open another activity before load ads, and return to the main activity, then it not showing a problem.

```
    W/Ads: Could not fetch ad response from ad request service.
       android.os.DeadObjectException
           at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.ac.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:148)
           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.k.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:247)
           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.l.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:1221)
           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.promise.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:46)
           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.c.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:150)
           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.b.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:19)
           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.y.call(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:1055)
           at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.z.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:75)
           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

Here is the code for load ads:

```
    private void loadads_ (){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " loading ads", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView2);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        } catch (Throwable e){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "erro loading ads", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

I created a backup, before add ads. That is working properly.

Comment: is it admob Ad?

Comment: Yes. Can you help?